# Hyper V Screen Resolution too Small

Tags: hyper-v

I have created a Windows 7 VM in Hyper V.

When I open it with the Hyper V console, the screen is way too small and the VM is unreadable because it's all too small.  I have set it to be 800x600 but that just makes the window tiny and not the desktop bigger.

Then I tried to RDP into it but that's worse.  Now the screen takes the whole of the hosts screen but the desktop is still way too small to read.

I have also tried mstsc /c:VM1 /w:800 /h:600 but it only creates a small window and the desktop is still too small to read.

I have turned off "Allow enhanced session mode" and that had no effect.

I would like to know how to get the resolution to be say 800x600 and have it appear big on my desktop screen and not in miniature.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Install the integration services. You should have an option in HyperV to insert the integration disk.  Once this is installed, you should be able to change the resolution.